# Pandas Equivalent of SQL CROSS JOIN (Cartesian Product)

Tags: python, sql, pandas, join

Let's say I had two tables:

Table1:

```
   col1  col2
      0     1
      2     3
```

Table2:

```
   col3  col4
      5     6
      7     8
```

In SQL, if I made the following statement:

```
Select *
From Table1, Table2;
```

I would expect to get back a table with all combinations from both tables:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
   0    1    5    6
   0    1    7    8
   2    3    5    6
   2    3    7    8
```

Is there a way to do the same thing with two dataframes in pandas?

Comment: I actually prefer the accepted solution here over the one linked to above (as it assumes "you have a key that is repeated for each row" in both dataframes).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A standard idiom is using the `merge` on a dummy column.

```
df1.assign(foo=1).merge(df2.assign(foo=1)).drop('foo', 1)

   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     0     1     5     6
1     0     1     7     8
2     2     3     5     6
3     2     3     7     8
```

Comment: In pandas version 0.23.4 one must give also `on='foo'` parameter to merge. Like `df1.assign(foo=1).merge(df2.assign(foo=1), on='foo').drop('foo', 1)`.

Comment: @samutamm it is required only if non-key columns across the DataFrames share the same name.

Comment: Good, thank you @cs95